# Browser remembers contenteditable sub-element after deleting?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `contenteditable` element, with a sub-element for styling.  I backspace enough to totally remove the subelement (the sub-element tag is totally gone, verify by inspecting the current page source).  I start typing again, and the sub-element tag *re-appears*.

Tested in firefox and chrome.  See in action:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <font color="#f00">
    backspace this whole line of text, 
    inspect the html to see that the `font` tag is gone, 
    then type to watch it magically reappear
  </font>
</div>
```

This behavior is both annoying and awesome.  I would like to:

1. Know how to keep the `font` tag from re-appearing.  i.e. when I backspace the whole font tag, and start typing again, it should not be in the `font` tag.
2. The browser is "remembering" the tag somehow, somewhere that isn't in the raw html.  This probably means that I can ***read*** and possibly ***write*** the "current tag" variable whatever it is.  E.g., when I backspace through the `font` tag in my example, the `font` tag disappears from the html.   The browser is storing this info: `<font color='#f00'></font>` somewhere *after it's been removed from the html*.  I want to access that info after I've backspaced it, and edit that to be, say, `color='#00f'` instead.  I could write a bunch of js to read and remember and deal with this stuff manually, but it would be awesome if I could just access it wherever my browser/window is currently keeping it.

Probably an answer to #2 makes #1 trivial.

Comment: I don't see this behavior happening - Chrome 102.0.5005.182 - Is the text supposed to remain black or become red again after I delete the text?

Comment: I'm on Chrome 105.0.5195.125  I'm also on Linux, but I can't imagine that it would be OS-specific.  Firefox 104.0

Comment: @caTS the text is always red, even after you backspace the whole thing and type some more.  However, after backspacing the whole thing, if you inspect the page source, you'll see that the `font` tag is gone.  It comes back when you start typing again.

Comment: But the text stays black after you delete all of it and type it in again... I'm asking if this behavior is the same for you.

Comment: Oh my... I just tried this code on Chrome iOS (87.0.4280.77) and the text comes back as red...

Comment: @caTS is the text black for you to begin with?  Mine is red, and after I backspace it and type some more it is still red.  I actually can't find a combo of keypresses to make it black at all.

Comment: No, after I backspace it, and type in text again, it is now black, so the font tag has disappeared. I think the version I am on "fixed" this. This is on a ChromeOS Chrome v102

Comment: @caTS what OS are you on and getting black text?  Can you be more specific about the behavior of the box when you delete/add text?

Comment: @caTS my chrome is later than yours!  :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249082/discussion-between-cats-and-him).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

After the `font` tag has been deleted, when the `font` tag appears again it changes the color of `font` tag to blue.

```js
  let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
    if (mutationRecords[0].type === 'childList') {
      const font = mutationRecords
        .filter(mutationRecord => mutationRecord.addedNodes.length > 0)
        .filter(mutationRecord => Array.from(mutationRecord.addedNodes).at(0).tagName === 'FONT')
        .map(mutationRecord => Array.from(mutationRecord.addedNodes).at(0))
        .at(0)
      if (font) {
        font.style.color = 'blue'
      }
    }
  });
  
  // observe everything except attributes
  observer.observe(elem, {
    childList: true, // observe direct children
    subtree: true, // and lower descendants too
    characterDataOldValue: true // pass old data to callback
  });
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="elem">
  <font style="color: #f00;">
    backspace this whole line of text, 
    inspect the html to see that the `font` tag is gone, 
    then type to watch it magically reappear
  </font>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do what you want with the `font` element, in this case it just changes its color from red to blue. I think that using MutationObserver is the best way to do this.